# How to set syncnode of a peer to true?

Tags: synchronization

I have a testnet connection with 3 clients. When I am doing getpeerinfo on 1 I am getting

```
[

    {
        "addr" : "172.20.61.111:63379",
        "services" : "00000001",
        "lastsend" : 1403246741,
        "lastrecv" : 1403246743,
        "bytessent" : 1074,
        "bytesrecv" : 1098,
        "conntime" : 1403246741,
        "pingtime" : 0.00000000,
        "version" : 70002,
        "subver" : "/Satoshi:0.9.2/",
        "inbound" : true,
        "startingheight" : 56114,
        "banscore" : 0,
        "syncnode" : true
    },
    {
        "addr" : "172.20.53.82:63416",
        "services" : "00000001",
        "lastsend" : 1403246741,
        "lastrecv" : 1403246743,
        "bytessent" : 149,
        "bytesrecv" : 1098,
        "conntime" : 1403246741,
        "pingtime" : 0.00000000,
        "version" : 70002,
        "subver" : "/Satoshi:0.9.2/",
        "inbound" : true,
        "startingheight" : 56114,
        "banscore" : 0,
        "syncnode" : false
    }
]
```

as a result of syncnode false this node is not syncing. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The syncnode concept was added in v0.8.2, to make sure we always have at least one connected peer from which we have at least once asked what their current blocks are. The name was pretty confusing, as it does not actually correspond to which peer we're downloading blocks from - just through which peer we actively seek to learn about blocks' existence.

v0.10.0 has a completely different synchronization mechanism (called headers-first), which does no longer have a syncnode. In fact, it downloads from all outgoing peers simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The p2p algorithm only selects one peer node to sync from. "syncnode" is a boolean that lets you know if that ip is the one you're currently downloading blockchain from.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2034 has this to say about it:

"There is one designated "sync node", from which the synchronization is supposed to happen.
getblocks messages are never sent to any but the sync node."

Comment: The idea presented in that issue does not actually correspond with what was implemented (in 0.8.2-0.9.x). As of 0.10.0, it's totally outdated.

Answer (score 0):

maxconnections=1
listen=0
connect={IP you want as your sync node}

That's only way to guarantee it, outside of modifying source.